# Wd Mycloud drive, files not showing on drive itself

Tags: server, mount, network-drive

I have installed ubuntu 19.10 and I have mounted my drive in /etc/fstab like this:

```
//192.168.1.194/Katon /mnt/mycloud cifs noperm,username=username,password=password 0 0
```

However when I copy files to /mnt/mycloud and go to the network drive the files are not actually there. How do I sync it?

Comment: i typed that wrongly, apologies should be 192

Comment: if you mount it without `noperm` but with guid and uid, the situation is the same? `sudo mount -t cifs -o username=${USER},password=${PASSWORD},uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g) //192.168.1.194/Katon /mnt/mycloud`. Does your share have nobody:nogroup ownership?

Comment: it works like this actually how do I put it properly into fstab now? @Gryu

Comment: you could run `id -u` and `id -g` in terminal and then paste the values into fstab. Also, what happens if you connect to it using nautilus? Does files are actually copied? And what is that share's provider? Is it windows sharing service or is it samba services?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Have you by any chance tried the `sync` command?